# react, webpack: avoid ".." in import statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm currently learning react and thus es6/es7 and webpack.

Coming from a largely python background I'm annoyed by the folder sensitive path declarations for import statements, i.e. the use of `../../` in import statements. This means if I move a file to a different directory, i need to change the import statements declared in the file.

Python's import statement doesn't have this issue. I'd like to mimic that behavior 
(search first a particular directory for this path, if not search this other base directory)
e.g. if i have the directory structure

```
myApp
    components
        component1.jsx
    stores
        store1.jsx
    views
        view1.jsx


node_modules
    react
    etc
```

in my view1.jsx I don't want to write

```
import Component1 from '../components/component1'
```

I want to write

```
import Component1 from 'components/component1'
```

or maybe even

```
import Component1 from 'myApp/components/component1'
```

just to make sure I don't have name collisions with some npm package I may be using.

What is the correct way of accomplishing this in webpack? Is it using alias?

Comment: Check `resolve.modulesDirectories` webpack parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following @zerkms recommendation. `resolve.modulesDirectories` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a loader to accomplish this, https://www.npmjs.com/package/future-require-loader. It will autoload a path anywhere three underscores surround a partial file path `___filename.js___`. it also allows folder paths: `___folder/filename.js___`. it will attempt to match the first file path that includes the string so you will want to include folders if there could be a conflict.