# React import root path helper

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react because I have to import varies helper or component I have this problem

```
import approxPerDay from '../../../utils/approxPerDay.js'
import otherstuff from '../components/otherstuff'
```

and in another file it might be `import approxPerDay from '../utils/approxPerDay.js'`

It's really hard and time consuming to find is the relative path is. Is there any npm or helper can solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755065/es6-import-from-root Though the question is posed for es6 directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react, webpack: avoid “..” in import statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311484/react-webpack-avoid-in-import-statements?rq=1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on your module bundler. For `Webpack 2` you can do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...

    resolve: {
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
            path.resolve(__dirname + '/src')
        ],
        alias: {
            src: path.resolve(__dirname + '/src')
        }
    },

    ...
}
```

the same for `Webpack 1`:

```
module.exports = {
    ...

    resolve: {
        root: [
            path.resolve(__dirname  + '/src')
        ],
        alias: {
            src: path.resolve(__dirname  + '/src')
        }
    },

    ...
}
```

Than you will be able to use `src` as a native path like this:

```
import approxPerDay from 'src/utils/approxPerDay.js'
import otherstuff from '../components/otherstuff'
```

Comment: The trick is `resolve.modules` for WP2 and `resolve.root` for WP1. Alias just provides the "alias" name for the directory. Without it, you will be able to import your files like this: `utils/approxPerDay.js`, but with the alias it's more clear: `src/utils/approxPerDay.js` IMHO.

Comment: Look in the documentation https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Answer (score 11):

I was experiencing a similar problem. I finally resolved it by following this article: https://medium.com/@ktruong008/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4338fbca7e3d

1. Create a .env file in the root of the react app
2. Add a line `NODE_PATH = src/`

That worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

The thing you are asking is called "absolute import".
"create react app" already provides a standard solution and recommends creating a jsconfig.json file in your root directory of react project.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Later you can import components as such:

```
import Button from 'components/Button';
```

Go to this link of official docs related to importing component and there u will find absolute import section:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/

And Yes don't forget to restart your react server after doing the changes : )

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specify the .env file and relative path, the IDE needs to know about it.
For this, the following lines worked for on my IDE.

File
`jsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

[image]