# how to specify a path relative to the project root?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is what one of my import paths look like:

```
import Register from "../../../../../../../../src/components/register/Register";
```

How can I specify paths relative to the root of the project folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React import root path helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063592/react-import-root-path-helper)

Answer (score 1):

Module builder configuration specifies it.

For e.g. Webpack 2:

```
module.exports = {
...

resolve: {
    modules: [
        'node_modules',
        path.resolve(__dirname + '/src')
    ],
    alias: {
        src: path.resolve(__dirname + '/src')
    }
},

...}
```

Then you can import like this:

```
import Register from "src/components/register/Register";
```

Comment: In what file do I put this configuration code?

Comment: "webpack.config.js" is the name of the file.

for more reference: [link](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)