# How can i access more simple to access any component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a bit complex structure, to access for a function inside of itemTypes i have to do this: `import { ON_BOARDING_STEPS } from '../../../constants/itemTypes'`, i think this is too hard to read `'../../../'`

```
├── components
│   ├── App

│   ├── Editable
│   │   ├── formQuestion
              Editable.jsx
├── constants
│   └── itemTypes.js
```

i am using vite from reactjs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063592/react-import-root-path-helper should help you

Comment: take a look at [webpack resolve.alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `jsconfig.json` file on the project's root and add this code to it.

instead of `'../../../constants/itemTypes'` then you can write `'constants/itemTypes'`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```